# Redirection in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner in ruby on rails. So the scenario is that I am in an index page and I am performing an update in a form displayed on that page. Once the update is done I wish to redirect it back to the index page and reflect the update.
i tried this,

```
 def update
    format.html { redirect_to action: "index"}
  end
```

This does not seem to work. Any place I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work, becuase `format` is not defined. Either use

```
def update
  # some logic...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to action: "index"}
  end
end
```

or drop `respond_to` and leave just:

```
def update
  # some logic...
  redirect_to action: "index"
end
```

`respond_to` is a method that lets you define how your controller action will respond to given format, e.g:

```
def update
  # some logic...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to action: "index"}
    format.json { render json: {bleh: :blah} }
  end
end
```

Comment: I see ! Thanks that makes sense. Appreciate your quick reply, will accept it after the duration.